# IIS 7 IP Addresses and Domain Restrictions - denying all

Tags: iis-7, security, http-status-code-403

This evening I noticed a brute force attack attempt from the same IP address on several of our websites hosted on the same IP address.  The attempt was to exploit a bunch of php-related vulnerabilities.

As I get notifications on all of these, I simply added the incoming IP address in IIS Manager/IP Address and Domain Restrictions - set to deny, then left it.

No more notifications, so I figured everything was good.

Later when I attempted to access any of our websites, I got a 403 access denied error from any IP address I tried to access these sites from.  I do have one site that I have explicit allow rules set for other IP addresses, which I was able to access, however all the other sites do not have this special rule.

To get all the sites working again, I added an Allow rule where I added an IP address range is the web server's IP address, and Mask or Prefix = "(1)".

Here are the settings in IP Address and Domain Restrictions:

```
Mode: Allow
Requestor: ([my server's IP address])(1)
Entry Type: Local
```

So what I'd like to know is why this is now allowing access to the rest of my sites.  Did I mistakenly delete a value that should have been there before?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From what I read [here](http://books.google.ca/books?id=uTlwa8ce7KgC&pg=PT570&lpg=PT570&dq=iis%20domain%20restrictions%20Requestor%3a&source=bl&ots=cYaU7UvQUF&sig=mrVv8FC1_12HTq41jxYvqqErPQM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=U-U6T5z5Lcbb0QGTi9nQCw&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=are%20restrictedBy%20default,%20domain%20name%20restrictions%20are%20disabled&f=false), By default, domain name restrictions are disabled.

Comment: This answer (which is merely a link to purchase a book now out of print) does nothing to help anyone else experiencing the issue.